# Retrieving Microsoft Live calendar events between 2 dates

Tags: rest, calendar, live

I'm currently working on requesting a list of events between 2 dates via Microsoft Live's REST API. I am able to pull back a list of events through the following request URL:

```
https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/events
```

However, this returns a list of events that *does not* have any specific date frame. For example, I'd want to call a request similar to this:

```
https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/events?startDate=2015-02-15&endDate=2015-03-15
```

I haven't been able to find any useful Microsoft documentation in their disorganized mess of "documentation", so my questions are:

**1 - What changes need to be made to the first endpoint above for something like this to work?**

**2 - What time format does Microsoft use for this kind of request?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the answer in the middle of a Microsoft [documentation page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826523.aspx).

> Get a limited number of events based on their starting and ending times in Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) format by using the `start_time` and `end_time` parameters

To answer my own questions:

**#1** - The following endpoint works:

```
https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/events?start_time=2015-02-15T00:00:00Z&end_time=2015-03-15T00:00:00Z
```

**#2** - The time format is as follows:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'
```